# Run time error 5981 when trying to create MS Word doc files from Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created an MS word document which is aimed at downloading field values from a table (query) and creating a report for each record within the table and saving it in a specified directory.
Unfortunately, after trying everything, i continue to get the error 5981 (Impossibile to open the memory macro). I am almost positive that all of the code is fine. Below is my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Public Sub LetteraPromossi()


  Dim rstStudentiPromossi As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim appWord As New Word.Application
  Dim strPercorso As String
  strPercorso = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\"
  Const conPercorso As String = "C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Andrea Lenti\MS Access\eserciziVBAAccess2010\"

  DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
  'Esegui le query di aggiornamento che sostituiscono i campi Null con ""

  DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryEliminaNulliDaIndirizzo"
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryEliminaNulliDaCittà"
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryEliminaNulliDaCAP"
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryEliminaNulliDaProvincia"

  DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)


  rstStudentiPromossi.Open "qryStudentiPromossi", _
                            CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly

  Do Until rstStudentiPromossi.EOF

      With appWord
        .Documents.Add strPercorso & "comunicazioni.dotx"
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, Name:="studente"
        .Selection.TypeText rstStudentiPromossi!Nome & _
        " " & rstStudentiPromossi!Cognome
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Indirizzo"
        .Selection.TypeText rstStudentiPromossi!Indirizzo
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Città"
        .Selection.TypeText rstStudentiPromossi!Città
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, Name:="CAP"
        .Selection.TypeText rstStudentiPromossi!CAP
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, Name:="provincia"
        .Selection.TypeText rstStudentiPromossi!Provincia
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Media"
        .Selection.TypeText rstStudentiPromossi!Media
        .Visible = True
      End With
      rstStudentiPromossi.MoveNext
  Loop
  rstStudentiPromossi.Close
  Set rstStudentiPromossi = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes raises the error?

Comment: .Documents.Add strPercorso & "comunicazioni.dotx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you ever save or close the Word documents -- 1 for every record in the recordset. There is a limit to how many documents you can have open at the same time before running out of memory. I can't tell how many records you are dealing with, but you'll probably want to save and close them within the loop to free up memory for the next one.

Comment: Thanks pteranodon.  Would you be so kind to help me with the code to do so? Perhaps show me the command and where it should go? This is my first time dealing with this topic and that example comes directly from an exercise book. Strangely the book doesnt mention anything like that..    BTW- there are only 5-10 records in the recordset...

Comment: Is the error is happening on the first time that line runs? Does it ever open Word?

Comment: It happens each time and Word never opens.